# How to get current transaction in ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have a project that written ASP.NET Boilerplate (assembly version=4.0.2.0).

I want get current transcation object in Application layer. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post the code in question? It's not only helpful for us, but also for future visitors.

Comment: @Devilscomrade hi, thanks for answer. My question is common. ASP.NET Boilerplate is using UnitOfWork and  I want get current transaction object in Application layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get current unit of work with using `IUnitOfWorkManager`.

```cs
IUnitOfWorkManager _unitorWorkManager;
//...
[UnitOfWork]
public void Test(){
    /*
    Your code
    */
    
    _unitOfWorkManager.Current//gives you current unit of work
        .SaveChanges();//same thing with transaction.Commit();
}
```

If your class inherits something like `AbpController`, `BackgroundJob`, `AbpServiceBase` etc..., you can also use `CurrentUnitOfWork`.

```cs
//...
[UnitOfWork]
public void Test(){
    /*
    Your code
    */

    CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();//same thing with transaction.Commit();
}
```

You can check https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work for more information.

---

Edit: I guess it is not possible to get it in application layer directly since it need dbcontext parameter. What about creating a domain service which provides ActiveDbTransaction. You can create an interface for that in `*.Core` project and define it where you can access to dbcontext

```cs
public interface IMyDbContextActiveTransactionProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the active transaction or null if current UOW is not transactional.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IDbTransaction GetActiveTransaction(ActiveTransactionProviderArgs args);
}
```

Implement it someplace you can access to dbcontext

```cs
public class MyDbContextActiveTransactionProvider: IMyDbContextActiveTransactionProvider, ITransientDependency {
    private readonly IActiveTransactionProvider _transactionProvider;
    public MyDbContextActiveTransactionProvider(IActiveTransactionProvider transactionProvider){
        _transactionProvider = transactionProvider;
    }

    IDbTransaction GetActiveTransaction(ActiveTransactionProviderArgs args){
        return _transactionProvider.GetActiveTransaction(new ActiveTransactionProviderArgs
        {
            {"ContextType", typeof(MyDbContext) },
            {"MultiTenancySide", MultiTenancySide }
        });
     }
}
```

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Using-Stored-Procedures,-User-Defined-Functions-and-Views/index.html#DocHelperMethods

Comment: Hi, thanks you for answer. I want get current transaction, but your code is for current UnitOfWork

Comment: Can you please try [IActiveTransactionProvider](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp/Data/IActiveTransactionProvider.cs)

Comment: Thanks you for comment. I tried IActiveTransactionProvider , but it accept [ActiveTransactionProviderArgs](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp/Data/ActiveTransactionProviderArgs.cs). This interface implemented by [EfCoreActiveTransactionProvider](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/EfCoreActiveTransactionProvider.cs). I have a problem. If I use this, add reference EFCore layer to Application layer, that I don't want this (

Comment: It has 3 implementations. [NhActiveTransactionProvider](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.NHibernate/NHibernate/NhActiveTransactionProvider.cs), [EfActiveTransactionProvider](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.EntityFramework/EntityFramework/EfActiveTransactionProvider.cs) and [EfCoreActiveTransactionProvider](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/EfCoreActiveTransactionProvider.cs). Which ORM do you use in your project?

Comment: `Abp.EntityFrameworkCore` package already has that implementation. You should be able to use it with via `IActiveTransactionProvider` interface

Comment: Yes, but I need  ActiveTransactionProviderArgs for GetActiveTransaction method of IActiveTransactionProvider. It is key value pair. Value is must be DbContext's type, Therefore I must add reference EFCore layer to Application layer, because I want get current transaction in Application layer. But I don't want add reference

Comment: Thanks you for answer, abi  !